# Python NumPy array: Setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I'm writing code to process a CFD result file, ".vtk", of a structured grid.
And I always end up with this problem:

> "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence"

The problem comes when I try to reorder all the data the code is reading as shown here:

```
    # Get nodes list and clean the extra nodes
    nodes_list = vtk_to_numpy(nodes_obj).tolist() #nodes = nodo de las mallas
    vof_list = vtk_to_numpy(vof_obj).tolist()
    to_sort = [tuple(nodes_list[x] + [vof_list[x]])  for x in range(len(nodes_list))]
    vof_list = None
    nodes_list = None
    ll = []
    for i in range(len(to_sort)): # What are we doing?
        ll.append(str(to_sort[i]))
    ll = list(set(ll))
    to_sort = []
    for i in range(len(ll)):
        to_sort.append(eval(ll[i]))


    # Set the type for each column
    dtype = [('x', float), ('y', float), ('z', float), ('vof', float)]
    to_sort = np.array(to_sort, dtype = dtype)

    ## Orders the Matrix according to X, Y, Z
    to_sort.sort(order = ('x', 'y', 'z'))
```

The problem, specifically, comes at this point:

```
    # Set the type for each column
    dtype = [('x', float), ('y', float), ('z', float), ('vof', float)]
    to_sort = np.array(to_sort, dtype = dtype)
```

I have tried to change the dtype from float to object, but this makes the function going into a huge infinite loop.

What can I do?

'to_sort', just before the error is a list that looks like this:

```
   [[(0.26602, 0.0011719, 0.0011719, [-4.5626e-06, -0.00012627, -0.00012222])],
   [(1.6254, 0.0011719, 0.0011719, [1.4921e-05, -0.00037639, -0.00037658])],
     ....
     ...
   [(2.2793, 0.0011719, 0.0011719, [5.2438e-06, 8.4728e-05, 8.4849e-05])]]
```

Comment: Please trim your code down to a [mcve]. You may benefit from [ask].

Comment: Is `to_sort` a list of lists, per chance?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. Yes it is.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I will delete part of it. Sorry. By the way, I think I can. This code previously worked for a smaller file of an unstructured grid case without problems.

Comment: You can. It creates a structured array.

Comment: We should be able to copy and paste your code to run it.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I trimmed the code. Do any of you have some idea of what could be wrong?

Comment: For this dtype the data input has to be a list of tuples.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga your answer does not work. Unfortunately I get the exact same error.

Comment: @hpaulj, I think it is a list of tuples the input.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are trying to create a structured array, but passing a list-of lists. It then tries to set that list (a squence) as an element, and it fails. Instead, you need a list of tuples. 
[**From the docs**:](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#filling-structured-arrays)

> If you fill it in row by row, it takes a take a tuple (but not a list
>   or array!):

So try a quick fix:

```
to_sort = np.array(map(tuple, to_sort), dtype=dtype)
```

Comment: I'm trying it now. I let you know asap the result (probably it will take 2 hours to reach that part of the code again). Thanks. I'm still wondering why with a smaller and slightly different file the code worked.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work, same error happens.

Comment: One way or other you have to make sure `to_sort` is the correct list of tuples.  All of it; and no guesses.  It's not the kind of example that we can replicate,

Comment: @MichelePaoletti my "solution" was a shot in the dark. It's impossible to say exactly how to fix your problem, because we do not know what your data looks like, because you haven't provided a reproducible example, but the problem is that you need to feed `np.array` an appropriate list of tuples...

Comment: what I'm doing is to try to see what 'to_sort ' looks like exactly before the error. I'm drastically reducing the number of elements but it should give an idea. I will post here an update soon. @hpaulj and and juanpa.arrivillaga. Thanks anyways for the help. I'm really appreciating it.

Comment: @hpaulj I've posted what 'to_sort' looks like

Answer (score 0):

```
alist = [[(0.26602, 0.0011719, 0.0011719, [-4.5626e-06, -0.00012627, -0.00012222])],
```

[(1.6254, 0.0011719, 0.0011719, [1.4921e-05, -0.00037639, -0.00037658])]]

works with this a compound dtype:

```
In [39]: np.array(alist, dtype=('f,f,f,3f'))
Out[39]: 
array([[ ( 0.26602   ,  0.0011719,  0.0011719, [ -4.56260022e-06,  -1.26269995e-04,  -1.22219994e-04])],
       [ ( 1.62539995,  0.0011719,  0.0011719, [  1.49210000e-05,  -3.76390002e-04,  -3.76579992e-04])]], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<f4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<f4'), ('f3', '<f4', (3,))])
```

That is, there are 4 fields, 3 are floats, and one contains 3 floats.  The result is a (n,1) array.

There are 2 levels of [] which produce the 2d array shape.  1 level of () defining the record.  But within that there's another [], defining an array within the record.

and to change field names

```
In [41]: data =__
In [42]: data.dtype.names
Out[42]: ('f0', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3')
In [43]: data.dtype.names=['x','y','z','vof']
In [44]: data
Out[44]: 
array([[ ( 0.26602   ,  0.0011719,  0.0011719, [ -4.56260022e-06,  -1.26269995e-04,  -1.22219994e-04])],
       [ ( 1.62539995,  0.0011719,  0.0011719, [  1.49210000e-05,  -3.76390002e-04,  -3.76579992e-04])]], 
      dtype=[('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4'), ('vof', '<f4', (3,))])
```

Or alternatively

```
dt = np.dtype([('x', float), ('y', float), ('z', float), ('vof', float, 3)])
In [53]: data['vof'].shape
Out[53]: (2, 1, 3)
In [54]: data['x'].shape
Out[54]: (2, 1)
```

If that's not the dtype that you want, you'll have to review how you construct `to_sort`.